# Range attribute for the decimal value

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I have the following

```
/// <summary>The project budget</summary>                
[Range(0, double.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Must be a positive number")]
public double? Budget { get; set; }
```

But the values like "7.5" or "7,5" (culture format variant) does not pass the validation. Why?

[image]
[image]

Could the nullable `double?` type be the cause?

**PS.** Just tested, the non-nullable `decimal` value does not change the behavior, I have the same results..

Comment: Decimal validation generally is broken in (especially older) versions of unobtrusive validation. And completely forget about trying to get it to work with localized versions of numbers. You may have some success with the Globalize library but you're probably better off rolling your own to be honest - I've yet to come across a good client-side validation library that can do this.

Comment: Just a shot in the dark, but have you tried it with a non-nullable type?

Comment: non-nullable value does not change the behavior, just tested...

Comment: regular expression does not work either....  (